# Form not returning data

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form on my site. When the user submits the form I get the email response but there is no form data returned. All I see is

```
Company:
Name:
Email:
Phone:
```

The form html is below:

```
<form method="post" action="send_survey.php" class="survey" >
            <header><a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/PTS_Survey_logo.jpg" alt="Patterson Tubular Services Logo"></a>
        Customer Survey</header>
        <fieldset>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append icon-group"></i>
                        <input type="company" id="company" required placeholder="Company name">
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i>
                        <input type="name" id="name" required placeholder="Your name" >
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append icon-envelope-alt"></i>
                        <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="Your e-mail">
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append icon-phone"></i>
                        <input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
                    </label>
                </section>

            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="button">Submit the survey</button>
            </footer>
        </form>
```

The php code is below:

```
<?php

/*Subject and email variables */

    $emailSubject = 'PTS Site Test';
    $emailTo = 'testemail@testemail.com';

/* Gather form information */

    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];           

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Company: $company <br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>

EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail ($emailTo, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered */

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.cudd.com/PTS-2014/index.html">';

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you closing the submit button with `</button>`? It is an `input` submit button and should not be closed.

Comment: None of your `<input>` elements have `name="XXX"` attributes.

Comment: Turn on *all* errors when working on code: Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. That was it. I was looking it over most of the day and couldn't make sense of it. Knew it was something simple i was missing.

Comment: @user2529658: Please mark an answer, since both fixes your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML form input is set in POST by the element's `name` attribute, not its id. You should set the `name` attribute to the same as the id on each of your input elements.

Comment: Or just change `id=` to `name=`, as he's probably not using the IDs for anything.

Comment: This ^.  I came here to say it.

Answer (score 2):

You have no `name` attribute on any of your inputs

Change:

```
<input type="company" id="company" required placeholder="Company name">
```

To:

```
<input type="company" name="company" id="company" required placeholder="Company name">
```